# Disable wrong phone number link detection UITextView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, textview

My textView detects a number "123456789" as a phone number. The automatic link detection changes its color and highlights it when the user taps it.

The thing is that I want to disable the automatic link detection of that textView for **just that number**.

I have tried to remove the phoneNumber as a detectorType but in that case the textView does not recognize any phone number in the textView.

Does someone know what can I do to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable autodetection for whole textview and add links to needed numbers. And you should know them exactly to easy find them or at least their 'good' pattern, to use regex to find matches and set links

I guess that phone numbers use URL scheme `tel` like `tel:1-408-555-5555` for example.

```
let phoneRange = textView.text.range(of: "1-408-555-5555")
let phoneURL = URL(string: "tel:1-408-555-5555")!
let linkString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)
linkString.addAttribute(.link, value: phoneURL, range: phoneRange)
textView.attributedText = linkString
```